# Definition for some order set

Tags: order-theory

For any two elements, namely a and b, there exists c s.t. a<c and b<c.

I’m pretty sure this is the definition for some order set, but I just don’t know the name of it.

Comment: The property that every pair of elements has an upper bound is one of the properties of a directed set. Is that what you’re thinking of?

Comment: @Joe that is indeed the name of the concept defined in the question. I think you should just go on and answer, perhaps elaborating a bit more.

Comment: @amrsa, I will leave that to someone more knowledgeable/experienced with the topic.